# Spring REST: HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I am getting the above error, due to a problem with Jackson attempting to deserialize my POJO.

I've debugged the code and it returns false within Jackson's ObjectMapper:

```
public boolean canRead(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, MediaType mediaType) {
    JavaType javaType = getJavaType(type, contextClass);
    return (this.objectMapper.canDeserialize(javaType) && canRead(mediaType));
}
```

this.objectMapper.canDeserialize(javaType) returns false which causes the error

My Controller is as follows:

```
@Controller
public class CancelController {
    @Autowired
    private CancelService cancelService;

    @RequestMapping( value="/thing/cancel", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json" )
    public @ResponseBody CancelThingResponseDTO cancelThing(@RequestBody CancelRequestDTO cancelThingRequest) {
        return cancelService.cancelThing(cancelThingRequest);
    }
```

My CancelRequestDTO implements Serializable:

```
public class CancelRequestDTO implements Serializable{
  /**
   * Default serialization ID
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  /**
   * Reason code associated with the request
   */
  private final String reasonCode;
  /**
   * Identifier of the entity associated with the request
   */
  private final EntityIdentifier entityIdentifier;

  /**
   * Default constructor
   *
   * @param reasonCode Reason code associated with the request
   * @param entityIdentifier Identifier of the entity associated with the request
   */
  public CancelRequestDTO(String reasonCode, EntityIdentifier entityIdentifier) {
    super();
    this.reasonCode = reasonCode;
    this.entityIdentifier = entityIdentifier;
  }
  /**
   * @return Returns the reasonCode.
   */
  public String getReasonCode() {
    return reasonCode;
  }
  /**
   * @return Returns the entityIdentifier.
   */
  public EntityIdentifier getEntityIdentifier() {
    return entityIdentifier;
  }
}
```

My Spring configuration is as follow:

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Scan for stereotype annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cancel.web.controller" />

<bean id="viewNameTranslator"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />





<bean id="jsonView"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" >
    <property name="contentType" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

<!-- Register JSON Converter for RESTful Web Service -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Anyone know what might be causing this deserialization issue?

Thanks

Comment: What is the full code for your DTO/POJO that it is erroring out on?

Comment: Just added it, may it be related to absence of setters?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Caused by my DTO not having a default constructor with setters! So looks like an inaccurate Exception from Jackson

Comment: Yes, their exceptions can me misleading.

Comment: In my case, my DTO has a Map as on of its attributes.  When I added @JsonIgnore to this attribute it fixed my problem.

Comment: In my case a created a method `getCompiled` and `isCompiled` for attribute `compiled`, and the error comes from Jackson .

Answer (score 11):

For anyone who still facing this problem, you cannot have two `@JsonBackReference` in a single class, add value to one of the reference like this `@JsonBackReference(value = "secondParent")` also add the same value to `@JsonManagedReference(value ="secondParent")` in parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I have always done this using the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver. It seems that it is not understanding the content type that you are passing it. This is the configuration that I typically use for doing what you are trying to do:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <map>
                            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                        </map>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                        <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This video goes through doing exactly what you are trying to do with consuming the service through jQuery in the UI:

http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/springmvc-intro

Comment: Still the same, although the error is charset related, it's to do with serialization in the ObjectMapper