# Using Java Written @RequestBody grails

Tags: java, spring-mvc, grails, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails 2.3.5.
In my project I have created RestWebservice using Spring @Controller annotation.
When I'm trying to sent JSON request to it its showing
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException] to request in view with name 'error'.

So I thought that its not able to cast JSON to Object So I have added

```
compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.8"
        compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.8"
```

in my BuildConfig.grovvy
Even after that issue exist.

```
@Controller
public class VendorController {
@RequestMapping(value ="/api/anonymous/book.dispatch", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public vender validateVendor(@RequestBody Vender vender)
{
try {
//Logic***
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
return vender;
}
return vender;
}
```

My dto is having default and parametarized constructor and its serialized
Thanks

Comment: The object to which you want to deserialize JSON string, is it serializable? check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548182/spring-rest-httpmediatypenotsupportedexception-content-type-application-json

Comment: Add your controller code and the request details to the question