# Sprint Rest Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Calling a Controller from a Java service I have this issue

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
>   type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

I do not understand what's wrong with my Java code

```
String url3 = "http://localhost:8889/galian/S/S/S/claimsWS/getContract1";
ContractDto contractDto = new ContractDto("Test", "20161111", "idTest");
RestTemplate restTemplate3 = null;
try {
    restTemplate3 = getRestTemplate(new URI(url3));
}
catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
//headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<ContractDto> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<ContractDto>(contractDto, headers);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
Object responseEntity = restTemplate3.postForObject(url3, requestEntity, Object.class);
Map<String, Object> responseObject3 = restTemplate.postForObject(url3, contractDto, Map.class);
```

DTO

```
public class ContractDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7597862463769066562L;

    protected String contractId;
    protected String claimDate;
    protected String insuredObjectIdentifier;

    public ContractDto() {
    }

    public ContractDto(String contractId, String claimDate, String insuredObjectIdentifier) {
        this.contractId = contractId;
        this.claimDate = claimDate;
        this.insuredObjectIdentifier = insuredObjectIdentifier;
    }

    public String getContractId() {
        return contractId;
    }

    public void setContractId(String contractId) {
        this.contractId = contractId;
    }

    public String getClaimDate() {
        return claimDate;
    }

    public void setClaimDate(String claimDate) {
        this.claimDate = claimDate;
    }

    public String getInsuredObjectIdentifier() {
        return insuredObjectIdentifier;
    }

    public void setInsuredObjectIdentifier(String insuredObjectIdentifier) {
        this.insuredObjectIdentifier = insuredObjectIdentifier;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@Lazy
@RequestMapping("/claimsWS")
@Transactional
public class ClaimsController {
...
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getContract1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void getContract1(@RequestBody ClaimContractCriteriaDto contractCriteriaDto, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ....
        writeResult(response, contratBean);
    }
```

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444855/spring-rest-post-json-requestbody-content-type-not-supported)?

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548182/spring-rest-httpmediatypenotsupportedexception-content-type-application-json)?

Comment: This is no matter with my issue